# Basic Networking: Connecting two private networks

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

First off - I am a newbie to network stuff so please don't flame me for not understanding a basic function right ^^'

To my question:

How do I need to configure my Modem and Router to **get two separate networks** (10.0.0.xxx and 192.168.5.xxx)?

I want to have to following configuration:

[image]

---

My Status quo:

**AKNW_M:**

[image]

**AKNW_R:**
(I can't upload pictures...)

Local IP Address 192.168.5.1

Subnet Mask 255.255.255.0

Gateway 10.0.0.138

Local DNS 10.0.0.138

---

**Comment on the answer of Vinh Tran**

I configured AKNW_M and AKNW_R as you said:

AKNW_M:

```
IP = 10.0.0.138
SN = 255.255.255.0
DHCP = ON
```

AKNW_R:

```
LOCAL IP = 192.168.5.1
LOCAL SN = 255.255.255.0
LOCAL Gateway+DNS = 192.168.5.1
LOCAL DHCP = ON
```

(as Automatic/DHCP config did not work, I configured it on static:)

```
WAN IP = 10.0.0.50
WAN SN = 255.255.255.0
WAN Gateway+DNS = 10.0.0.138´
```

After I added a Hostname on the AKNW_R the router appeared on the AKNW_M.

Sadly I do not have a internet connection.
I can not access the AKNW_M on 10.0.0.138
But I can access AKNW_R by 192.168.5.1 and 10.0.0.50
(both tested from AKNW_HWK)

Now, as I view the Status on the AKNW_R with said config:

WAN:

```
Connection Type...Static  
IP Address...10.0.0.50 
Subnet Mask...255.255.255.0 
Gateway...10.0.0.138 
DNS 1...192.168.5.1 
DNS 2...10.0.0.138
```

It seems that my AKNW_R adds the 192.x.x.x adress automatically as the first DNS even while it's 0.0.0.0 in the config-page.

LAN:

```
IP Address...192.168.5.1 
Subnet Mask...255.255.255.0 
Gateway...192.168.5.1 
Local DNS...192.168.5.1
```

---

**It works now!**

Here is what I configured, thanks to @VinhTran I figured out the last piece of the puzzle:

**AKNW_R:**

```
Advanced Routing > Operating Mode > Gateway
WAN Connection Type > Static IP
WAN IP Adress > Choose a client IP from the first network (10.0.0.xxx)
WAN Subnetmask > Same as 10.0.0.xxx
WAN Gateway and DNS > 10.0.0.xxx's Modem/Router IP
Router IP > 192.168.5.1
Subnetmask > 255.255.255.0
Gateway and DNS > 192.168.5.1
DHCP > ON
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try these steps to configure your design network model:

1. Config AKNW_M modem to connect aDSL, then enable [DHCP server] on
   this device, following subnet 10.0.0.xxx.
2. Connect WLAN Extender A, WLAN Extender B & TV-Box to AKNW_M **LAN port**. You can use a layer 2 (normal) switch to extend AKNW_M LAN port for future use.
3. Connect AKNW_R to **AKNW_M LAN port** also. And plug network cable from **AKNW_M LAN port** to **AKNW_R WAN port**.
4. On **AKNW_R** control panel, configure its WAN (internet) IP address by getting from DHCP, or by static IP but follow this form:

> WAN IP address: 10.0.0.xxx
>
> Subnet: {Follow subnet of **AKNW_M**}
>
> Gateway: {**AKNW_M LAN IP address**}
>
> DNS: {**AKNW_M LAN IP address**}

5. Enable [DHCP server] on AKNW_R with IP subnet 192.168.5.xxx, with gateway & DNS are AKNW_R LAN IP address.

Hopeful you success configure your network!

Comment: First off - thanks for helping me!

As this comment would be too long, I am adding it to my main post...

Comment: @KaiAdam: I't quite weird about DNS on AKNW_R. May client in 10.0.0.xxx subnet (WLAN Extender A, WLAN Extender B, ...) can still connect to the internet?

Also please change the [DNS 1] on AKNW_R WAN to AKNW_M IP address.

Comment: Here is my AKNW_R config:
http://imgur.com/ETlcW4p
And that's what AKNW_R says about it's status even after rebooting:
http://imgur.com/B9B5eVA
And AKNW_M:
http://imgur.com/s04oMGa

Comment: @KaiAdam: Please change AKNW_R WAN IP to 10.0.0.50 (http://imgur.com/ETlcW4p) as you mentioned above. AKNW_R WAN IP must be different from AKNW_M LAN IP.

And please make sure client in 10.0.0.xxx subnet (WLAN Extender A, WLAN Extender B, ...) can still connect to the internet?

Comment: I got the WAN IP back to 10.0.0.50 and checked if the TV-subnet is still working and it is. However there is still no internet connection.

Comment: @KaiAdam: May you please show your 192.168.5.xxx client IP table (cmd > ipconfig /all) which is gotten from AKNW_R DHCP, and a tracert result from this client to 8.8.8.8 (cmd > tracert 8.8.8.8)? You can add it to a new answer on this topic.

Comment: @VinhTran ipconfig: http://imgur.com/aWpvz6w tracert: http://imgur.com/2zs19Wf

Comment: From your tracert result (and from requirement in seting-up IP address from your ISP) I think your AKNW_M just 's refusing all LAN connection except from IP subnet 10.0.0.xxx, @KaiAdam! Does your AKNW_M has firewall function or not? Is there anything you can show from AKNW_M configuration page?

Comment: @VinhTran it has a firewall, I disabled it to test if that's the reason but I coudn't connect either.

AKNW_M Interfaces: http://imgur.com/r6jXlmk

Comment: @KaiAdam: as showing on the screenshot & your listed, you're properly configuring AKNW_R and AKNW_M for your desire network layout. The problem is AKNW_M modem doesn't accept packet from another IPs except 10.0.0.xxx. I'm very sorry I can't help you anymore. Should you contact your local ISP for further support or any information? Wish you have success soon!

Comment: It works now! I just needed to set the routing operating mode from ROUTER to GATEWAY! Thanks! :)

Answer (score -1):

Refer to these images.

ipconfig:

[image: http://imgur.com/aWpvz6w]

tracert:

[image: http://imgur.com/2zs19Wf]